# is it possible to retrieve data from google maps for an application?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, smartphone

I am currently developing an application for a smartphone and i was wondering is it possible to retrieve directions from google maps,when given the current location and the desired destination, to the application?

And just an outline on how to do this if possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

inde, there is a GOOGLE MAPS API here :[Site](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use: [Google Maps API External Library](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

See this : [Loading a Maps API site in a Native Android Application](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/android_v3.html)

Comment: Your answer appears to be a *stub*. Please [provide context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for the link you have provided.